# How to combine multiple Expressions in a List<Expression> into a single one to use with LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui

I have a list with multiple expressions. I had to generate them by analysing the filters (using Kendo UI for MVC).
I succssesfully generate the different parts of the where clause but then i can't combine all of them into one single expression.
For example in my list i have two expressions:

```
p.N == "t"
p.Y == "x"
```

At the end my code returns `p.N == "t" AndAlso p.Y == "x"` so my where clause looks like this: `db.Table.Where(p.N == "t" AndAlso p.Y == "x")` which is not working and i don't know if it is because im not separating the different criteria with && or some other error i cannot identify.
Here is my code:

```
var resultExp = expressions.Skip(1).Aggregate(expressions.FirstOrDefault(), 
                (exp1,exp2) => Expression.And(exp1,exp2));
            var r = resultExp as Expression<Func<VwInformacaoUtilizador, bool>>;
```

My objective is to combine all of the expressions in this list so my where clause correctly queries the database based on the filters i've received.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Upon request, here is the code for clarification.

```cs
if (filter is CompositeFilterDescriptor complex_Descriptor)
                    {
                        foreach (var filterDescriptor in complex_Descriptor.FilterDescriptors)
                        {
                            var i = filterDescriptor as FilterDescriptor;
                            switch (i.Operator)
                            {
                                case(FilterOperator.Contains):
                                    body = Expression.Call(
                                        Expression.Property(parameter, i.Member)
                                        , typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains") ?? throw new Exception()
                                        ,Expression.Constant(i.Value)
                                    );
                                    expressions.Add(body);
                                    break;
                                case(FilterOperator.StartsWith):
                                    body = Expression.Call(
                                        Expression.Property(parameter, i.Member)
                                        , typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) }) ?? throw new Exception ()
                                        ,Expression.Constant(i.Value)
                                    );
                                    expressions.Add(body);
                                    break;
                                case(FilterOperator.IsEqualTo):
                                    body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, i.Member),
                                        Expression.Constant(i.Value));
                                    expressions.Add(body);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    return exp;
                            }
                        }
                    }
}

var resultExp = expressions.Skip(1).Aggregate(expressions.FirstOrDefault(), 
                    (exp1,exp2) => Expression.And(exp1,exp2));

return resultExp;
```

Comment: The truth is, I did not understand the question.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Looks fine to me.

Comment: @Sweeper The lack of lambda parameter (`p => `)?

Comment: How do you generate `expressions`? And what is `p` inside them? Looks like parameter, but then why they are not lambda expressions? Please show the building code, the answer depends on that. For instance, if all these expressions use one and the same `ParameterExpression` variable called `parameterExpr`,  then simply do `var r = Expression.Lambda<Func<VwInformacaoUtilizador, bool>>(resultExpr, parameterExpr);`

Comment: To clarify the question: My goal is to dynamically generate a Where clause. I receive filters and then build them with that. Imagine they want all the users whom username starts with 'm' and First Name starts with 'a'. i want my method to return an expression with the correct parameters:

`db.TableUsers.Where(getWhereClause(request))`
where getWhereClause returns: `p=> p.Username.StartsWith('m') && p.FirstName.StartsWith('a')`

i edited my original question with the requested code

Comment: Well, I see variable `parameter` in the posted code. See the end of my previous comment, just replace `parameterExpr` with `parameter`

Comment: @IvanStoev, that was the solution, many thanks!!